# Passing a function to catchError

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, rxjs

I defined a simple function that will open a `MatSnackBar` and display the error message when a get request returns any error

```
handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    this.snackBar.open(err.message)
    return throwError(err)
}
```

So when I subscribe to an observable in the constructor I pass the above function to `catchError`

```
constructor(private snackBack: MatSnackBar) {
...
this._obv$ = this.myService.getTypes().pipe(
  catchError(this.handleError)
)
...
```

When the error is triggered the `err` passed to the `handleError` is correct but `this.snackBar` is `undefined`.

The problem disappear when I use the `handleError` function like this

```
this._obv$ = this.myService.getTypes().pipe(
  catchError(err => this.handleError(err)
)
```

What's the difference and why is the `snackBar` instance `undefined`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The problem

The issue is that a when a function is called on an object, the object is implicitly passed as that's functions context (its `this`). Sometimes you'll see this invocation style called a *method* rather than a *function*.

Methods are implicitly given the object whose properties they're allowed to operate on. You can, however, make this relationship explicit.

`this.handleError`, doesn't call the function, it just passes a reference to it. Now `catchError` doesn't know that it needs to call `this.handleError(err)` instead of `handleError(err)`.

In general, if a function uses the `this` keyword, then the caller is responsible for supplying the `this` context. Using dot notation makes this pretty intuitive but causes strange behaviour in the corner cases.

---

## Solution:

One fix is to use a lambda function to do that step for you. Lamda function (using arrow `=>` syntax) always retain the context relative to where they are defined. So in this case, `this` refers to what you expect.

Another solution is to bind the right object to the function call (which lets you call the function as a method on the bound object). This workaround is more robust in some cases as it lets you bind **any** context to a function. In this case, however, you're just binding the current context.

**like this:**

```ts
constructor(private snackBack: MatSnackBar) {
...
this._obv$ = this.myService.getTypes().pipe(
  catchError(this.handleError.bind(this))
)
...
```