# Angular - interface remains uninitialized

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple **service** class (not a component).
In this service class I use a simple interface, which looks like this:

```
export interface IErrorModel 
{  
    message: string;
}
```

This interface is used inside my service and is initialized in the constructor, as well, like this:

```
export class LoginService {

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {this.errorModel = {message:'test'}}

    headers = new HttpHeaders();
    private logInUrl = 'https://localhost:7268/api/User/Login';
    private logOutUrl = 'https://localhost:7268/api/User/Logout';
    private errorModel: IErrorModel;

    logIn(loginModel: LoginModel): Observable<any> {
        this.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

        return this.httpClient.post(this.logInUrl,loginModel, {headers: this.headers, withCredentials:true, responseType : 'text'})
        .pipe(
            tap(data => console.log('All:',JSON.stringify(data))),
            catchError(this.handleError)
        );
    }

    logOut(): Observable<any> {
        return this.httpClient.post(this.logOutUrl, null, {responseType: 'text', withCredentials: true})
        .pipe(
            tap(data => console.log('All:',JSON.stringify(data))),
            catchError(this.handleError)
        );
    }

    private handleError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
        let errorMessage = '';
    
        this.errorModel = err.error;
     
        if(err.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
            errorMessage = `An error occured: ${err.error.message}`;
        }
        else {
            errorMessage = `${err.error}` //want to use errorModel.message here instead of err.error
        }
        console.error(errorMessage);
        return throwError(()=> errorMessage);
    }
}
```

Later, when I assign value to "message" and for example print it in the console, it gives error that errorModel is undefined.
Why is this happening?

**Update** -> The whole point of this process is that my error handling from the API returns exceptions like this:

```
{
  message: "exception";
}
```

So I want to de-serialize this message into an object. And this object is IErrorModel with its property - message. So I can use this property for Angular error handling. Thats all.

Comment: can you share the code where you are changing the `message` attribute, also how are displaying the message inside the `HTML`, basically if you can also share the `TS` code and the `HTML` where you are using this `LoginService` would be great

Comment: Yes, in a moment I will update the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare this way

```
private errorModel: IErrorModel = <IErrorModel>{};
```

Comment: Hm can I ask - I read something about using methods inside catchError method is quite specific and tricky. Do you know why?

I read this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69093746/passing-a-function-to-catcherror

Comment: I've never used methods inside the catchError to be honest. I usually do something like this:

`getError(err: HttpErrorResponse) {
    const backendError = JSON.stringify(err.error);
    const obj = JSON.parse(backendError);
    return throwError(
      obj.errors || err?.error?.message || 'Some error message'
    );
  }`