# handling 401 in angular, how does pipe work really?

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 14 and making a post request to my json server using the pattern like this:

```
myApiCall(data:any): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post<any>(url, data).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
}
```

( as specified in https://angular.io/guide/http)

And then wanted to add 401 (unauthorized) handling to handleError

so I added this block

```
  if (error.status===401){//UnAthorized
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
  }
```

to my handleError like so:

```
private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
  if (error.status===401){//UnAthorized
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
  }
...
  return throwError(
    () => new Error('Something bad happened; please try again later.')
  );
```

}

I can see in debugger that this.router.navigate(['login']); is hit, but it does not navigate to the login screen.  same code does work in another place.
The error in chrome console is :

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of (has file and line see below for details) undefined (reading 'router')
    at handleError (line where this.router.navigate(['login']); is)
    at catchError.js:10:39
    at OperatorSubscriber._error (OperatorSubscriber.js:23:21)
    ...
```

The top in call stack in the error is the .subscribe after myApiCall...

So what happens to handleError when I call

```
this.router.navigate(['login']);
```

Does it cause a return? And if so what gets returned ?

**UPDATE**

After Igor's suggestion of adding

```
return of([])
```

**AND** declaring handleError with **()=>{}** syntax instead of normal, it worked.

I wonder why the second part is needed. I still suspect it has something to do with how pipe works.

This works:

```
private handleError = (error: HttpErrorResponse) => { 
  if (error.status===401)//UnAthorized
  {
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
    return of([]);
  } 
  ...
  return throwError(
    () => new Error('Something bad happened; please try again later.')
  );  
}
```

This does not

```
private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse){ 
  if (error.status===401)//UnAthorized
  {
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
    return of([]);
  } 
  ...
  return throwError(
    () => new Error('Something bad happened; please try again later.')
  );  
}
```

After this.router.navigate instead of hitting return, control is transferred to the caller that results in an error that mentions router.

Why?

**SECOND UPDATE**:

Actually the first part (return of...) is not necessary to make it work, only the second (making it a lambda expression) is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
myApiCall(data:any): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post<any>(url, data).pipe(
    catchError((err) =>
        if (err.status===401){
          // Redirect if unhautorized
          this.router.navigate(['login']);
        }
        ...
    );
}
```

Note the lambda syntax of the error handler declaration. It is required in order to pass in the context (this). Without it the 'router' is not known hence the error. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69093746/passing-a-function-to-catcherror)

Comment: thank you that works, but why the same does not work from handleError? Isn't the only difference that it's a named function rather than anonymous one?

Comment: In your `handleError` are you returning `of(EMPTY)`, and are you returning your `handleError` function?

Comment: Yes I am. - return of([]); -  The exact same function but declared using => syntax works even if I name it, but using normal syntax does not (borks at that router.navigate line)

Comment: The problem here is that `handleError` is a method (belongs to the service) and not a simple function declared outside of the class. If you want to use a method, you need to [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) its context (i.e. tell `catchError` what `this` is), or use an arrow function which will [preserve the contex of creation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions): `catchError((err)=>this.handleError(err))`.

Comment: This should be a separate question to allow a complete explanation, and it has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69093746/passing-a-function-to-catcherror)

Comment: I just checked and return of([]) can be removed and it still works so the gist of your answer being correct is not the return statement, but the lambda syntax which also explains the error I get back. As such I think  the "why" of that very much belongs in THIS question. I updated your answer to match and to also correct the code syntax, hopefully it gets approved.